# Oracle performance issues with linguistic compare in DevExpress DataGrids

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use an oracle db where the standard comparison method is binary. There is a function that loops over a view which will get fast results in standard compare mode which works perfect. When the mode is switched to linguistic for case insensitive search

```
alter SESSION set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
alter SESSION set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
```

The execution time switches from 0,01 Second to whooping 22 Seconds. This can be also achieved directly on DB level when changing the session there.
Since devexpress has its own internal "where" builder (like selections for 'last week' / 'last year' etc in datagrids) I have to use these generated oracle statements.

The case insensitive mode is needed but so slow. Is there any way to tell devexpress to optimize database access maybe without altering the session? Comparing with "toUpper" values would be much faster for example.

already tried

```
  DevExpress.Data.Helpers.ServerModeCore.DefaultForceCaseInsensitiveForAnySource = true;
```

but this didn`t change anything.

Thx a lot, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The **DefaultForceCaseInsensitiveForAnySource** option should be the simplest way to enable a case-insensitive search, but it's important that it works only with the binary comparison mode. Using this feature with linguistic comparison does not make sense and can lead to unpredictable results.

If for some reason the use of **DefaultForceCaseInsensitiveForAnySource**
with the binary comparison mode does not meet your requirements, you can improve the linguistic search performance by creating [linguistic indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1006421) in your database.

If you have additional questions regarding this case, please create a ticket in the [DevExpress support center](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list). Our support team will conduct more thorough research than is possible in the SO thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When using the option with binary search the results are fast but still case sensitive. 
DX document says it only workds in server mode, which I don't really know what that refers to. Is there another switch that has to be turned on to get case insensitive results in the dx data grid? I've looked through many tickets but the solutions don't work for me or they refer to custom queries (CustomBuildCriteria) - there must be a simple way for this

Comment: Server mode is a set of data sources which allows to perform data bound operations at the server side (here is a [doc link](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8398/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/data-binding/large-data-sources-server-and-instant-feedback-modes?p=netframework)
I am pretty sure that you are using it, because if you don't filtering operations are performed locally and therefore server settings don't affect their performance.